# AWS Codedeploy failing to deploy on EC2 without any error logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy, aws-pipeline

I am deploying a spring boot jar in a EC2 instance from code pipeline using code build and deploy. CodeBuild is working fine and the artifact is getting uploaded in S3.

When the CodeDeploy starts, it will be in process for 2-3 mins and fail in the fist step. with this error

[image]

this is the error description

[image]
CodeDeploy service is running fine and all the other setup looks good. Also not seeing any logs in CodeDeploy logs in EC2. please help out on identifying the issue.

Here is my appspec file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
- source: /
  destination: /home/ec2-user
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
  - location: fix_previleges.sh
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
  - location: start_server.sh
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
  - location: stop_server.sh
    timeout: 300
    runas: root
```

Comment: Is the CodeDeploy agent installed on the EC2 instances? See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html

Comment: Yes. its installed and running

Comment: What exactly are your scripts?

Comment: Here are my scripts - 
fix_previleges.sh

`#!/bin/bash
chmod +x /home/ec2-user/umbookings-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
chmod +x /home/ec2-user/start_server.sh
chmod +x /home/ec2-user/stop_server.sh`

Comment: start_server.sh

`#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/ec2-user/umbookings-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &`

Comment: stop_server.sh

`sudo pkill -f 'java -jar'`